# stop firebug from re-requesting html source

Tags: firebug

I am working with a page that takes about 10-15 seconds to load, because it runs a huge SQL query, and it seems that firebug re-requests the source every time i try to use it. Has anyone else run into this? Is there a way to turn this off?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is your server-side code sending HTTP cache-control headers? If not, you could try adding them. If it is, and you are still seeing the problem, you could try installing a web cache proxy on your development machine and configure firefox to connect through it.

If you cannot change the server-side code to add cache-control headers, you can write an proxy that forwards requests to your server and adds the headers to the responses it returns.